# mysqli_insert_id ()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is it safe to use `mysqli_insert_id()` when the database is heavily used and more than one id maybe inserted in the same time, or it will get only the id that inserted by a query from this user..

Comment: it will give you the id only which is inserted by last insert query with that connection so dont worry to use it.

Comment: Please refer to this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264282/mysqli-insert-id-what-if-someone-inserts-another-row-just-before-i-call-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_insert_id()` is specific to the database connection , it returns the ID of the row which you  inserted most recently.