# Get the id of the just inserted row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm want to insert the id of every item in the cart to the database and couple this invoice line to an invoice that just has been created in the same case.
at the moment if i press the button its adding a new invoice to the database and after this its adding every single product in the cart but now i need to replace the 1 in the second query with the invoice id that just has been created. How can i get this to work?

```
  case "apply":
  $curdate = date('Y-m-d');
  // new invoice
  $sql = "INSERT INTO invoice (user_user_id, dates) VALUES ('1', '$curdate')";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  // for each item in cart insert into invoiceline
  foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
    $car = $item["id"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO invoice_line (car_car_id, invoice_invoice_number) VALUES ('$car', '1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  }
    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
  break;
}
}
```

The invoice_id is not the primary but a foreign key, the table doenst have a primary key so i dont think i can use mysqli_insert_id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_insert\_id: What if someone inserts another row just before I call this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264282/mysqli-insert-id-what-if-someone-inserts-another-row-just-before-i-call-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

or, object oriented style:

```
$inserted_id = $con->insert_id;
```

***$inserted_id*** will have the value of just inserted row (should be auto-increment in your table).

So, your second query will look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO invoice_line (car_car_id, invoice_invoice_number) VALUES ('$car', '$inserted_id')";
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed should have looked more before coming here because i was trying with the mysqli_insert_id already but forgot the $con